# Can i buy these lights and be able to use them without a plug in?

Tags: studio-lighting, portable

Photography Studio 600W Strobe Flash Speedlite Light Lighting Softbox Kit X1T3 (Contains Andoer MD-300 strobes)
I am trying to buy these lights off of ebay, and want to use them for a wedding shoot. I will not have access to a power outlet...so im wanting to know if anyone can tell me if this will work. Im sorry im having such a difficult time trying to understand the description.. HELP!!!

Comment: Is the kit you are looking identical to [this one](https://smile.amazon.com/Andoer-Monolight-Lighting-Unbrella-Photography/dp/B01LYWO2GL/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1502485371&sr=8-3&keywords=andoer+flash+kit)? I did some ebay searches, but ebay links aren't persistent and it's hard to guess. Can you quote the description here?

Comment: This isn't what you asked, but buying something like this for wedding shoot without having experience beforehand seems like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @ccuprak Could you provide a link to the specific product you are considering?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a portable external power source that can supply the strobes with a 120V/60Hz electricity. Something like [this unit](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/917729-REG/photogenic_956055_ion_pure_sine_wave.html) that could supply approximately 500 full power flashes to each of both strobes. For a bit more, you can get the [same unit with an extra battery](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/967031-REG/photogenic_956062_ion_inverter_with_battery.html) that would double your capacity to about 1,000 full power pops with both strobes.

There are strobes with built-in batteries for such 'location' types of shoots, but they aren't cheap, either. If you are trying to do it on the cheap you're probably better off looking at something like battery powered speedlights or bare bulb flashes. The [Godox X1 system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/) integrates cheap manual speedlights, TTL speedlights, bare bulb units, and small studio strobes into the same wireless control system. The [Godox AD200](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06X1FBC3F) is a 200Ws battery powered strobe. If you don't need that much power, the speedlights are more affordable.